# Selecting an element with multiple classes in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, traversal

I want to select an element which has a few classes

Something like this HTML:

```
<div class="myclass fclass sclass tclass"></div>
<div class="myclass tclass"></div>
<div class="myclass sclass tclass"></div>
<div class="myclass fclass tclass"></div>
<div class="myclass fclass sclass tclass"></div>
```

I only want to select the element with the `myclass tclass` classes.

I don't really want to do it in a way where I have to know every class, like this:

```
$(".myclass.tclass").not(".fclass, .sclass")
```

Comment: ...and the question is? `:)`

Comment: In this particular case, you could probably do `$('[class="myclass tclass"], [class="tclass myclass"]')`, but once it gets over two classes, it gets complicated.

Comment: Or maybe `if ($('.myclass.tclass').attr('class').split(/\s+/).length == 2) {... has only those two ...}`

Comment: @Tats_innit I only want the element/s that only have the classes .myclass.tclass

Comment: @Jared Farrish your first example is interesting it works but only when in that exact so it is limited and as you mentioned it is apparently trickier for more than 2 classes

Comment: I think you would probably be best creating a custom plugin or selector to allow you to match `n` number of classes. Even with the `filter()` method in my and undefined's answer, it's still sorta limited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May not work great as a callback with a named function (if you need it done with different class types), but the demo shows it works:

```
$('.myclass.tclass').filter(match_exact_class);

function match_exact_class() {
    return $(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/).length == 2;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/9bc4qjn4/1

As a single call:

```
$('.myclass.tclass').filter(function match_exact_class() {
    return $(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/).length == 2;
});

$('.myclass.tclass.sclass').filter(function match_exact_class() {
    return $(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/).length == 3;
});

$('.myclass.tclass.tclass.sclass').filter(function match_exact_class() {
    return $(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/).length == 4;
});
```

I suspect you could roll a simple plugin or custom selector and then split on the selector, something like:

```
var selector = '.myclass.tclass.tclass.sclass',
    sel_match = selector.split('.').length;

$(selector).filter(function match_exact_class() {
    return $(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/).length == sel_match;
});
```

Simple custom selector:

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.expr[':'], {
    matcls: function(elem, i, match){
        return elem.className.split(/\s+/).length == match[3].split(/\s+/).length;
    }
});

console.log($('div:matcls("myclass tclass")'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/9bc4qjn4/4

Comment: thanks this is exactly what I needed, very interesting way of doing. though am surprised others have not come across such a situation before as I searched on here or maybe they are smarter than me and figured same as you.

Comment: Take a look at the customer selector. Might need some debugging, and could be slow on lots of matches. But it should be a start.